# orchard contenttype get data from 2 different databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

My situation is that i have an external database and i should present the information in an orchard hp. The customer wants also to set new information and both should be shown via projection.

Short with simple example type book:

`Books` are in an external db.

`Books` should be set in orchard, in the orchard-db not in the external-db.

The query - projection should get both `books`-entities and displayed.

Is there a simple orchard-way to implement my problem?

Unfortunately, I did not find any sample for what ... Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: is there ever a way to implement this?

Comment: Please set my reply as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described I understand that in short you want to manage some data from an external data source as Orchard content items. This is well possible, it needs the following to happen:

- Create a content type for your data.
- Periodically pull in changes from the external data source.
- Programmatically create content items of your new type from the data pulled in.

Since this is not an everyday scenario I don't know of any tutorials out there for this although there is at least one sample: the [External Pages](https://orchardexternalpages.codeplex.com/) module does pretty much this, by pulling in Markdown pages from a Mercurial repo.